# Ubuntu 16.04: no module named 'lsb_release' error while creating startup disk

Tags: 15.10, 16.04, startup-disk-creator, startup-disk

I have tried creating startup disk for Ubuntu 16.04 many times, using the **Startup Disk Creator** but all in vain. Half way, it always gives me the same error, 
No module named `lsb_release`. What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you attempting to create a **16.04** startup USB, but under **an earlier version** of Ubuntu? (eg. 14.04 LTS, 15.04, 15.10) *What version of Ubuntu are you currently using?*

Comment: yes that's right. i was trying from 15.10

Comment: I may add here that I tried the linux live usb creator in Windows and successfuly created the live usb stick and now am running 16.04. I wuld still love to find the solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

For **15.10** or **15.04**, I would recommend using *Gnome Disk Utility* (aka 'disks').

Simply, click on 'cog' icon (top right) and select 'Restore Disk Image' to copy the ISO file to a 2GB (or 4GB) USB stick.

**Note:** *Make sure you select the correct target media, and don't override something important.*

--

For **Windows 7 Pro/Windows 10**, use 'Rufus' utility [https://rufus.akeo.ie/]

Select the ISO file, choose GPT partition, etc.